# How do you add java libraries to the Apache Hive container?

Tags: amazon-s3, hadoop, hive, hive-metastore, apache-hudi

I get a org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found message when trying to write a hudi table into S3.  I'm using the official Apache Hive HMS image.

```
  hive-metastore:
    container_name: hive-metastore
    hostname: hive-metastore
    image: 'apache/hive:4.0.0-alpha-2'
    ports:
      - '9083:9083' # Metastore Thrift
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: metastore
      HIVE_METASTORE_WAREHOUSE_DIR: /home/data
    volumes:
      - ./data:/home/data
```

How would you add org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.1 to the image?

Answer (score 0):

I used the env option listed at https://chetnachaudhari.github.io/2016-02-16/how-to-add-auxiliary-jars-in-hive/